# compile errors w/wininet & winhttp in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, wininet, winhttp

Strangely I had this working before but I reinstalled my system, upgraded to w7 and now I can't seem to get this code to compile.

The problem is that I'm using winhttp.h in most of my application, but I have a simple FTP client object that I wrote using wininet.h functionality. I can't seem to get the application to compile now, no matter how/where I include which headers.

Currently I have in my stdafx.h:

```
#include <winhttp.h>
```

And in my ftp client .c

```
#include <wininet.h>
```

This compiles all objects successfully except for the FTP client object which fails with:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\WinInet.h(52) : warning C4005: 'BOOLAPI' : macro redefinition
>           c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\winhttp.h(45) : see previous definition of 'BOOLAPI'
>   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\WinInet.h(270) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '('
>   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\WinInet.h(270) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah got it, finally by moving the winhttp include into the cpp files and putting wininet into the ftp client header.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a clash between winhttp.h and wininet.h.